# Using apache poi to set password for a xlsx with hadoop filesystem api

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-poi

Is there any workaround to use hadoop filesystem api with poi to set password to xlsx file? The below code works in windows filesystem but how can I port it to use hadoop filesystem api? I did try converting outputstream to hadoop streams but no luck

```java
public class EncryptTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        encryptHSSF();
        encryptXSSF();

        for (final String file : new String[] {"test.xls","test.xlsx"}) {
            try (Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(file), "pass")) {
                System.out.println(wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void encryptHSSF() throws IOException, EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException {
        generateFile("test.xls");

        try (HSSFWorkbook hwb = (HSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new File("test.xls"))) {
            Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword("pass");
            hwb.write();
        }
    }

    public static void encryptXSSF() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        generateFile("test.xlsx");

        try (POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem()) {
            EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile);
            Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
            enc.confirmPassword("pass");

            try (OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs)) {
                try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("test.xlsx")) {
                    IOUtils.copy(is, os);
                }
            }

            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.xlsx")) {
                fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
            }
        }
    }


    public static void generateFile(final String filename) throws IOException {
        try (Workbook wb = filename.endsWith("x") ? new XSSFWorkbook() : new HSSFWorkbook()) {
            wb.createSheet("test").createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("Test");
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename)) {
                wb.write(fos);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

share  edit